# Stty getting insane on using Python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, debugging, subprocess, stty

I am facing a weird problem. Every time I call a particular command `cmd` via `subprocess.Popen(cmd).wait()`,  the stty gets bad (does not echo my further commands on the shell, newline does not work, etc.) when the command is over. I have to run `stty sane` to get the stty fine again. What could be the reason for this?

**Update** The command I am running is starting the [elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/) process. The command launches the process in the background.

Comment: What command are you executing?

Comment: why would you want to do elasticsearch stuff on the console via python when there is at least one phyton client for ES?

Comment: @Karussell Yes, I use pyes. But I could not find a way to start the elasticsearch server via pyes, which is what I am doing above.

Comment: in java you start a node via NodeBuilder - isn't that possible with pyes too?

Comment: @Karussell http://packages.python.org/pyes/guide/reference/java-api/client.html is the NodeBuilder API in java. But probably it is not available in pyes.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the command you're running is emitting some escape sequences into your terminal that are changing its mode or other settings. Programs that need the full terminal capability do that (e.g. text based editors).

Capturing the standard output of the program you're executing and preventing it from going to the screen might help. Have you tried that?